# Typescript React Discriminated Unions problem

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, interface, type-conversion

I'm trying to use Discriminated Unions on my React/Typescript project, but I've been getting some weird errors:

So, here is my types, the thing is, I want to use the annotation props only if the chart has the `showAnnotationButton = true`, because when I left it all on 1 type as optional props, in the code I got an error about the possibility of being `undefined`, and I'm trying to avoid having to expose each prop in the code like `updateAnnotationsPUT as (id: number, data: Item) => Promise<void>`

```
export type ChartProps = {
    ...
    /** Should show annotation button */
    showAnnotationButton?: false;
    ...
}
export type ChartWithAnnotationProps = {
    /** Should show annotation button */
    showAnnotationButton: true;
    /** Annotations array */
    annotations: AnnotationItem[];
    /** Chart Period (for Annotations) */
    chartPeriod: Date[];
    /** PUT call to update Annotation */
    updateAnnotationsPUT: (id: number | string, data: AnnotationItem) => Promise<void>;
    /** Date Options for the chart annotations */
    chartDateOptions: DateOptions;
} & ChartProps;
```

In my React element I have:

```
const element = (
        <>
            <SrOnly>
                <Link href={`#${skipChartAnchorId}`}>{i18n.skipChart}</Link>
            </SrOnly>
            <div className={scss.chartContainer}>
                <>
                    {showAnnotationButton && (
                        <Button
                            className={scss.showAnnotations}
                            onClick={() => setShowAnnotations(!showAnnotations)}
                        >
                            Show annotations
                        </Button>
                    )}
                    ...
                </>
                <HighchartsReact
                    containerProps={{
                        "data-component": "chart",
                        "data-observe-key": props["data-observe-key"],
                        className: className,
                        style: style,
                    }}
                    highcharts={Highcharts}
                    options={chartOptions}
                    ref={chartComponentRef}
                />
                {showAnnotationButton === true && (
                    <Annotations
                        showAnnotations={showAnnotations}
                        hideAnnotations={setShowAnnotations}
                        annotationsData={props.annotations}
                        onUpdateAnnotation={props.updateAnnotationsPUT}
                        chartPeriod={props.chartPeriod}
                        dateOptions={props.chartDateOptions}
                    />
                )}
            </div>
            ....
        </>
    );
```

Which shows the error on the `showAnnotationButton === true` condition:

> This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'false |
> undefined' and 'true' have no overlap.

And errors like this on the props

Any ideas? I went through a lot of Discriminated Unions articles, but no idea on how to solve this issue

> This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'false |
> undefined' and 'true' have no overlap.

Comment: Can you show how you defined your component? And how you use it?

Comment: @caTS I updated the code in the topic with the "full" element (it has a lot of other things within, left just the important parts)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to declare the type of `showAnnotationButton` as `boolean` not `false`

```
export type ChartProps = {
    ...
    /** Should show annotation button */
    showAnnotationButton?: boolean;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I changed it to boolean, but the problem still remains the same :/